# ActionView set to an item in support NavigationView not showing

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I'm using the support NavigationView in my navigation drawer to display menu of items.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_background"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_background"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    app:theme="@style/Text.DrawerItem"/>
```

I want to display a counter of connection requests next to a menu item.

I've tried to set the `actionLayout` in XML menu definition like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    ...
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_requests"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_swap_horiz_24dp"
        android:title="@string/connect_menu_connection_requests"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/connection_request_counter"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    ...
  </group>
</menu>
```

Layout of the ActionView `connection_request_counter.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:textColor="@color/brand_blue"
      android:text="5"/>
```

But at this point I can't see number 5 next to the item.

I've tried to set ActionLayout programatically as well:

```
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(mMenu.findItem(R.id.navigation_requests), R.layout.connection_request_counter);
```

But still no luck.

I can get reference to the TextView like

```
final TextView connectionRequestCounterView
            = (TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mMenu.findItem(R.id.navigation_requests));
```

Which actually returns a TextView instance, but even if I set a text to it, I can't see anything in the layout. Could that be related to the fact that I'm styling the menu items? (I set text color, tint and background of the menu items)

Here are my styles:

```
<style name="Text.DrawerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_dark_grey</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_default</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/text_color_dark_grey</item>
    <item name="fontPath">@string/font_aller_light</item>
    <!--<item name="android:background">@color/background_activity_default</item>-->
    <!--<item name="background">@color/background_activity_default</item>-->
</style>
```

`drawer_item_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!--To override the default grey background for selected item-->
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

and `drawer_drawablbe.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/background_activity_default"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item
    android:bottom="24dp"
    android:left="16dp">
      <bitmap
        android:gravity="left|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/my_drawer_logo"/>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

Where `@drawable/my_drawer_logo` is a PNG in different densities.

Any other ideas why I can't see the action view?

Comment: I've tried to recreate the issue, but I don't have a problem running your code.  Can you share `@style/Text.DrawerItem` ?

Comment: In fact, having continued to create the issue without success, can you the "@drawable/drawer_item_background" and the "@drawable/drawable_background" as well ?

Comment: @OYRM Thanks very much for looking into that. I've posted my styles and background drawables. However, I've tried to remove the background drawables and it did't help.

Comment: @OYRM I just checked view hierarchy and can't see the view in there either.. Even though in code I get a reference to the TextView and can set a text to it without an exception. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found out what was causing the issue. **For NavigationView to work properly with action views, you must use AppCompat support library version 23.1**

So instead of

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.3.0'
```

I had to update to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

which made the trick and the action view in navigation drawer's navigation view started showing properly, exactly as I wanted.

---

When updating to the new AppCompat version I came across several more problems like `ClassNotFoundException` showing up when starting the app, which I fixed by updating **all com.android.support libraries to the latest version**:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
...
```

Then I was still getting `NullPointerException` in my header layout set to the NavigationView. If you're setting `app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"` or similarly in code, in AppCompat version 22 it was possible to get the header view by `findViewById()`.

AppCompat version 23, though, uses RecyclerView for all the items including the header view, so the way to get reference to its views is following:

```
 mHeaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(HEADER_INDEX);
```

Where `HEADER_INDEX` is most likely 0 if you're not adding multiple headers.

Answer (score 2):

I can change the text of the counter easily enough.  However, The text view that I use is within a `LinearLayout`, and it has an android:id as well (I tried this without the `LinearLayout` without issue):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Given that, I am able to see, access and modify the text view within the main activity using the following :

TextView countText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCounter);

countText.setText("6");

Of course, I'm using a trivial method to calculate the value, just setting it to the value "6", but, I don't know what your counter structure actually looks like, and those are not the main concern of your question.

The issue with your ability to view the counter number remains a mystery.  See my questions above and we'll hammer out that element as well.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Comment: I've tried to wrap the TextView in FrameLayout and give it an ID. The app does not crash, but the text is still not visible. Damn counter.

Comment: @anoniim I've added my `onCreate` text for the Activity.  How does this compare to yours ?

Comment: After a couple more hours trying to find out what the *** is wrong I got it! I wasn't using the latest version of support library! Anyway, thanks a lot for all the effort!

Comment: Good deal, the dependencies can be a real hastle some time.  Can you post your old and new versions ?

Comment: You're damn right, over 4 hours lost just to show a stupid counter and the fix is almost a one-line change in `build.gradle`. I've posted an answer. Thanks again for your time, OYRM.

Comment: :) I've confirmed that changing my compilation and supports down to 22.+ in the module build.gradle under dependencies recreates the same issue.  Happy to help, good luck.