# (Android) app:actionViewClass doesn't seem to show

Tags: android

I was really wondering why i can't see the badge/counter at navigation drawer on the current build im working with. But on other build like newly created applicatoin with navigation activity it is showing. I followed Hari's blog: https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/android-adding-badge-or-count-to-the-navigation-drawer-84c93af1f4d9#.tknc8q6wy

Is it because of gradle build?

Im quite new to android and im lost what i missed...

on the activity_navigation_drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="Nav1 title"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_bookshelf"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_book_black_24dp"
        android:title="My Books" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_results"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_insert_chart_black_24dp"
        android:title="Nav3 title" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="Nav4 title" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

at Navigation Activity class onCreate method:

```
TextView navbookshelf=(TextView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_bookshelf));

navbookshelf.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
navbookshelf.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
navbookshelf.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
navbookshelf.setText("1");
```

Comment: please post you code ,it will be useful to recognize your question more easily

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem in `AppCompat` dependency under `23.0`. According to [ActionView set to an item in support NavigationView not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047941/actionview-set-to-an-item-in-support-navigationview-not-showing) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35067250/2668136) and by looking at the source code of the post you provided (specialy the [build.gradle](https://github.com/Hariofspades/NavigationDrawerLabel/blob/master/app/build.gradle)), you should update the dependencies to `23.1.1` as follows:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```