# Accessing and adding items to Spinner

Tags: android

I added a spinner to menu and I would like to add items dynamically to the spinner. But the problem is that Spinner is pretty deep in layouts.

I have a view of main action with navigation -> that includes main action view and contains NavigationView -> NavigationView has menu -> menu contains items -> one of items contains another menu and first item of that menu is Spinner.

Is there any better way to add dropdown to the menu? If not, how do I access the spinner?

Thanks for the help

Code:

MainActivity.kt:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    private lateinit var activities: Spinner

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_with_nav)
       activities = this.findViewById(R.id.menu_activity_select) //--- throws exception
```

activity_main_with_nav.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_main"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

main_menu.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_activity"
        android:title="@string/menu_activity">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_activity_select"
                android:title="@string/menu_activity_select"
                app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
                /> <!-- this is the spinner I am looking for -->
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_activity_activate_devices"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
                android:title="@string/menu_activity_activate_devices" />
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_activity_camera"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:title="@string/menu_activity_camera" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <group>
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_scan_qr"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_codigo_qr"
            android:title="@string/menu_scan_qr" />
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_calendar"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_month"
            android:title="@string/menu_calendar" />
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/menu_settings" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should not matter how deep the spinner is in the layout. If you are calling `findViewById()` in the correct view hierarchy, it should give you the instance of spinner. Once you get the instance of the spinner you just need to set the adapter with items. If you want to add items dynamically just add the new item in the whatever data structure have you used for the adapter. After then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Comment: Thats what i expected but it seems like it's nto working, cause it throws exception (findViewById(R.id.menu_activity_select) must not be null), I guest it's because I am including items of the main menu from xml? Or it should be working anyway?

Comment: Would you be able to post related code that you think not working?

Comment: As I said, you are not accessing the correct view hierarchy. You are accessing the menu in the onCreate(). Menus are not available in onCreate callback. Menus are available in onCreateOptionsMenu().   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus

Comment: I see, i tried to move it to onCreateOptionsMenu(), but it seems this function is never called cause I am using NoActionBar template. Where should I move it to?

Btw: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this relevant ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047941/actionview-set-to-an-item-in-support-navigationview-not-showing

Comment: Are you able to get the instance of Navigation View? If you can get then you can try something like navigationView.getMenu().getItem().getActionView().

Comment: Finally i find out how to get it: findViewById(R.id.nav_view).menu.findItem(R.id.menu_activity).subMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_activity_select), but it returns MenuItem and I need it like Spinner, and when I add as Spinner behind it, then it throws exception MenuItem cannot be cast to Spinner, so I guest the MenuItem is worthless for me

Comment: Oh god, finnaly got it, I have to call findViewById(R.id.nav_view).menu.findItem(R.id.menu_activity).subMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_activity_select).actionView as Spinner - then it works (wtf), but thank you sooo much for your help