# Android Action Menu "actionViewClass" Doesn't Work

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-menu, android-imagebutton, android-optionsmenu

I use built-in icon for the action menu item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/first_refresh_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"    <- here gets problem
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

If I use `android.widget.ImageButton`, the action icon becomes a grey rectangle:

[image]

If I use `android.widget.ImageView`, the action icon becomes invisible:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what about this link? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35067250/10247147

Comment: @Daniel.Wang No help, I didn't use `NavigationView` at all.